# Trying to horizontally center DIV

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to horizontally center the div id="lastrow"

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
    <div class="col-md-12">Name: <input type="text" id="name"><span class="vishid"> Name:</span></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Company: <input type="text" id="comp"><span class="vishid"> Company:</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
    <div class="col-md-12">Address: <input type="text" id="addr"><span class="vishid"> Address:</span></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">City: <input type="text" id="city"> ST: <input type="text" id="stat"> Zip: <input type="text" id="zip1">-<input type="text" id="zip2"><span class="vishid"> City:</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
    <div class="col-md-12">E-Mail: <input type="text" id="emai"><span class="vishid"> E-Mail:</span></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Phone: (<input type="text" id="area">) <input type="text" id="pho1">-<input type="text" id="pho2"> Extension: <input type="text" id="exte"><span class="vishid"> Phone:</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="lastrow" style="display: block;margin-left: 0;margin-right: auto; text-align:center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div>
        Message:&nbsp;
      </div>
      <div>
        <textarea id="mssg"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="recap" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="aewrwgtearhrtjtsryjEFEdUAPN5CrFuM5l_1ZdSu7OH_g"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure if you need the CSS file as most of it is regarding widths.

Thank you for your time,

Don

Comment: The last div is already horizontally centered...Please provide the rest of the CSS

Comment: Try `margin: auto` instead of `margin-right: auto`.

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina You're using bootstrap 3 or bootstrap 4

Comment: @Saravana running the fiddle in the post

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bootstrap grid system, which is row and col class, 
for example if you want to center the div write your div code between the following code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
              //insert your div code to center
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" 
  id="staticEmail" value="email@example.com">
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form- 
 label">Password</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" 
  placeholder="Password">
   </div>
  </div>
</form>
              <!-- a bootstrap col has 12 that's why am divide col by 4 to 
 center 4+4+4 = 12 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

//or follow this bootstrap forms layout to get this

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/

Comment: Sorry, I want the word "Message" to the left of the textarea field.  Currently, it is above the field.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bootstrap-4` call the default class `text-center` to align the div center. If you want to make the design better refer the [bootstrap form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/).

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">Name:
            <input type="text" id="name"><span class="vishid"> Name:</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-12">Company:
            <input type="text" id="comp"><span class="vishid"> Company:</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">Address:
            <input type="text" id="addr"><span class="vishid"> Address:</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-12">City:
            <input type="text" id="city"> ST:
            <input type="text" id="stat"> Zip:
            <input type="text" id="zip1">-
            <input type="text" id="zip2"><span class="vishid"> City:</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">E-Mail:
            <input type="text" id="emai"><span class="vishid"> E-Mail:</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-12">Phone: (
            <input type="text" id="area">)
            <input type="text" id="pho1">-
            <input type="text" id="pho2"> Extension:
            <input type="text" id="exte"><span class="vishid"> Phone:</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center" id="lastrow">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div>
                Message:&nbsp;
            </div>
            <div>
                <textarea id="mssg"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="recap" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="aewrwgtearhrtjtsryjEFEdUAPN5CrFuM5l_1ZdSu7OH_g"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```